# How do I get clipboard image data with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, clipboarddata

In Win 10 you can Win+Shift+S to take a screenshot of a given section of screen, and can then Ctrl+V into something like Discord and immediately send that screenshot to people.

I'm trying to get that data (presumably a bmp / png format file) from the clipboard using Python and the win32clipboard module, but it's not working and I'm not even sure my approach is correct:

```py
# Using Python 3.10.4
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
z = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats()    # returns '49161'
mem = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(49161) # returns b'x00\x00\x00\x00....'
dat = win32clipboard.GetGlobalMemory(mem)    # raises TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object

# ... don't worry I close the clipboard later.
```

I can't find any info on how to create a PyHANDLE object and I have a feeling that I'm going down the wrong way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.devdungeon.com/content/grab-image-clipboard-python-pillow

Comment: This does solve my immediate need, yeah, but I'd still like to know how the Win32 API handles this under-the-hood just because I think it would be great to know.

I tried looking through pillow's source code to get some answers, but the "meat" of the method in question is actually buried somewhere in the C code (and I don't have much experience with C right now).